# Error when implementing MWFeedParser

Tags: iphone, xcode, rss

I trying to use the MWFeedParser library. I think the problem is that I want to use a view controller with a table view to display the news. Now there comes nothing up in my table view when launching the app. The code for the news view controller looks like this:

.H:

```
#import "MWFeedItem.h"
#import "MWFeedParser.h"

@interface NewsViewController : UIViewController <MWFeedParserDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    // Parsing
    MWFeedParser *feedParser;
    NSMutableArray *parsedItems;

    // Displaying
    NSArray *itemsToDisplay;
    NSDateFormatter *formatter;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

}


// Properties
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *itemsToDisplay;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

.M:

```
#import "NSString+HTML.h"
#import "MWFeedParser.h"
#import "DetailTableViewController.h"

@implementation NewsViewController

@synthesize itemsToDisplay, tableView;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"News", @"News");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_news"];    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // Date
    // Setup
    self.title = @"News";
    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    parsedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.itemsToDisplay = [NSArray array];

    // Refresh button
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                                                                                            target:self
                                                                                            action:@selector(refresh)];
    // Parse
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/feed/"];
    feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
    feedParser.delegate = self;
    feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
    feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
    [feedParser parse];

    UIImage *someImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_active1@2x.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:someImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    static BOOL first = YES;
    if (first) {
        UIViewController *popup = [[Home1ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home1ViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:popup animated:NO completion:nil];
        first = NO;
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Parsing

// Reset and reparse
- (void)refresh {
    self.title = @"Refreshing...";
    [parsedItems removeAllObjects];
    [feedParser stopParsing];
    [feedParser parse];
    /*
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.tableView.alpha = 0.3;
     */
}

- (void)updateTableWithParsedItems {
    self.itemsToDisplay = [parsedItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                           [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date"
                                                                             ascending:NO]]];
    /*  self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.tableView.alpha = 1;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
                 */
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark MWFeedParserDelegate

- (void)feedParserDidStart:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Started Parsing: %@", parser.url);
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedInfo:(MWFeedInfo *)info {
    NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Info: “%@”", info.title);
    self.title = info.title;
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didParseFeedItem:(MWFeedItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"Parsed Feed Item: “%@”", item.title);
    if (item) [parsedItems addObject:item];
}

- (void)feedParserDidFinish:(MWFeedParser *)parser {
    NSLog(@"Finished Parsing%@", (parser.stopped ? @" (Stopped)" : @""));
    [self updateTableWithParsedItems];
}

- (void)feedParser:(MWFeedParser *)parser didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Finished Parsing With Error: %@", error);
    if (parsedItems.count == 0) {
        self.title = @"Failed"; // Show failed message in title
    } else {
        // Failed but some items parsed, so show and inform of error
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Parsing Incomplete"
                                                         message:@"There was an error during the parsing of this feed. Not all of the feed items could parsed."
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    [self updateTableWithParsedItems];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return itemsToDisplay.count;
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (item) {

        // Process
        NSString *itemTitle = item.title ? [item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Title]";
        NSString *itemSummary = item.summary ? [item.summary stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Summary]";

        // Set
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        cell.textLabel.text = itemTitle;
        NSMutableString *subtitle = [NSMutableString string];
        if (item.date) [subtitle appendFormat:@"%@: ", [formatter stringFromDate:item.date]];
        [subtitle appendString:itemSummary];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    }
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Show detail
    DetailTableViewController *detail = [[DetailTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    detail.item = (MWFeedItem *)[itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

    // Deselect
    [self->tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}

@end
```

In IB, I've dragged a table view onto the view and linked it to dataSource and delegate. But nothing shows up in the table view. 
Would really appreciate some answers/ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: in header you MUST HAVE UITableViewDelegate/UITableViewDataSource protocols:   @interface NewsViewController : UIViewController <MWFeedParserDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {..

Comment: 2)  Go back to the main storyboard file and "Control + Drag" from the tableview to the view controller and select "data source" and "delegate". This is how you tell the tableview where it is going to get it's data from, and if an event. Check UITableView in UIViewController http://kurrytran.blogspot.ro/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-and.html

Comment: I've done all this but i don't make any changes...

Answer (score 0):

i think you should uncomment the following line in your "updateTableWithParsedItems" method:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```